# How does Nebula have access to these memories?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, how does past Nebula have access to the memories of Nebula in the future timeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some sort of quantum entanglement I guess. There is a paradox in physics called the EPR (Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen). It is like spins of particles and stuff. I'm not going into details because my knowledge here is limited.

But, that is the idea in *Avengers: Endgame*. Because essentially, Nebula is an alien artifical intelligence and so her "components" possibly semiconductors behave exactly like quantum physics "tells" it to. Of course, all these possibilities are only possibilities. They need not even be so - since quantum physics as we know it is probabilistic in its current understanding.

Answer (score 16):

I don't recall the exact wording but there are TWO Nebulas (Past Nebula & Present Nebula) in 2014 (when Present Nebula travels back in time).

They share a common (quantum?) "network" in 2014 (I think that was the term) so Past Nebula has access to Present Nebula's memories and can display them to Thanos.

Think "Galactic Wifi"...they can share data because they are on the same network and frequency but only when they are both in the same time.

Comment: "They share a common (quantum?) "network"" -> Probably the most ridiculous convenience to the plot out of all conveniences in Marvel movies, which is saying something

Comment: @Fatalize Hey, I don't make this stuff up, I just repeat it. The idea was that the two Nebulas are linked (like galactic wifi :< ) so they can share data.

Comment: I know, it wasn't a criticism of your answer, which perfectly describes what was said in the movie (I'm not the one that downvoted btw)

Comment: What makes Nebula special in this regard?

Comment: Nebula is primarily *cybernetic*

Comment: Put the word [quantum before mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mind) and you have a hypothesis :)

Comment: EBONY MAW (2014): Sire, the file appears entangled. It was a memory, but not hers. There's another consciousness sharing her network...another Nebula.

THANOS (2014): Impossible.

EBONY MAW (2014): This duplicate carries a time stamp... from nine years in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Large portions of Nebula have been replaced with cybernetics. It's not really that the two Nebulas "share" this cybernetic neural network - it's that the two cybernetic neural networks are identical, but one is older. Present Nebula wasn't aware that going to the past would result in this security breach presumably because Thanos would have been the one fully aware of the changes he had made to her.

The presence of two Nebulas within the same time period results in both Nebulas picking up interference off each other.